# tensor differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations, tensors

I have a differential equation with a simple tensor.  The differential equation is $dy/dt = A^{-1}*D*y-y^{T}*T_{D}*A^{-1}*W*y$ where A, D, W are all matrices with A and D being diagonal matrices and $T_{D}$ is the 3-tensor that maps the vector y to a diagonal matrix (yes I could simplify the expression but these matrices have structural interpretations).  With a scalar this boils down to a Bernoulli differential equation, however, I'm wondering how things change with matrices and tensors especially.  A solution with steps would be helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean $(T_Dy)_{ij}=y_i\delta_{ij}$, or $(T_D(u,v))_i=u_iv_i$? How do you combine the first term which is a column vector with the second term which is a row vector?

Comment: $(T_Dy)_{ij} = y_i\delta_{ij}$.   Sorry I was writing this quickly and wasn't thinking this through.  Also, my tensor math is bad.

Comment: your equality in line 2 is non-sense.

Comment: Yeah I might have written it wrong.  I could think through the matrix math again.  What I mean though is T_{D} is a 3 tensor such that $y^T*T_{D}$ maps to $y_i\delta_{ij}$  sorry if that was confusing.

Comment: Also, the D should be a W and there is no D.  My fault I should have thought this true more in detail before posting.  Writing each element of the equation separately I have: $\forall i \in v: df_i/dt = 1/a_i*(\sum_{j\in v}w_{ij}*(1-f_i)f_j)$  which can be solved to yield: $ f_i = 1-(e^\lambda*e^{((\Sigma)/a_i)*t}/(\Sigma)$ with $\Sigma = \sum_{j\in v}(w_ij*f_j)$.  Side note, this paper has a solution to my problem I think: but I don't really understand Lie groups and the like well enough to understand:  http://bit.ly/2DrCPdR .